# Mixture of two independent exponential distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, convolution, exponential-distribution

Let's define two independent random variables, $x$ and $y$ as:

$x$ ~ $D_A$ = $\exp ( \alpha)$

$y$ ~ $D_B$ = $\exp ( \beta)$

where $x$ gives the time differences between successive events of type $X$, and $y$ gives time differences between successive events of type $Y$.

What is the mixture of the two distributions $D_M = F(\alpha, \beta)$, that gives random variables that correspond to time differences between successive events of *any* type ($X$ or $Y$)?

For example, here are the histograms for waiting times drawn from exponential distributions with parameters $\alpha$ = 0.1 and $\beta$ = 0.02, and the histogram of the mixture (all in log scale). I want to know the symbolic distribution $D_M$ that generates the third histogram (which is clearly not of exponential distribution).

**NOTE: The third histogram is erroneous** in the sense that it is the mixture of *identical* sample sizes drawn from the two exponential distributions $D_A$ and $D_B$, which does not comply with the idea that in any given timeframe, random Poisson processes with intensities $\alpha$ ≠ $\beta$ yield different event counts.

[image]

How does this relate to the convolution of the two distributions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N_A=(N_{A,t})_{t \geq 0}$ be the [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) counting the occurrences of the type $X$ events, with intensity $\alpha$. Let $N_B=(N_{B,t})_{t \geq 0}$ be the Poisson process counting the occurrences of the type $Y$ events, with intensity $\beta$.

Suppose these are independent.

The process $N_A+N_B$ counts occurrences of both types, and [is a Poisson process](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/122022/is-the-sum-of-several-poisson-processes-a-poisson-process) with intensity $\alpha+\beta$, and thus the waiting times between occurrences are IID exponential random variables with parameter $\alpha+\beta$ and thus mean $1/(\alpha+\beta)$.

---

Suppose $E\sim \textrm{Exp}(\alpha),F\sim \textrm{Exp}(\beta)$, independent. Then their sum is distributed with a pdf given by the convolution of their pdfs; [its solution is not exponential with parameter $\alpha +\beta$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/412849/does-the-sum-of-two-independent-exponentially-distributed-random-variables-with). So the convolution of the two distributions does not relate to the distribution of the waiting times of $N_A+N_B$. The distribution of the waiting times of $N_A+N_B$ can be recovered with $\min(E,F)$. Indeed:
$$P(\min(E,F)> x)=P(E>x)P(F>x)=e^{-(\alpha+\beta)x}$$
so $\min(E,F)\sim \textrm{Exp}(\alpha+\beta)$.

Comment: Thanks Snoop. However, I am struggling to make sense of your answer. What exactly N_A+N_B means? What is the sum of random processes? I am no mathematician, so please be patient. Also, see my edit to the post. Am I correctly calling this a 'mixture distribution'?

Comment: The process $N_A+N_B$ is simply the sum of occurrences of events of type $X$ and $Y$. At each time $t$, this equals $N_{t,A}+N_{t,B}$ that is the sum of occurrences of both types up to time $t$. As I mentioned in my answer, it seems to me that the pdf obtained by convolution is not what you're looking for, which is the distribution of the waiting times of $N_A+N_B$. 'mixture distribution' has many meanings in different contexts, so the matter of semantics is here fruitless in my opinion.

Comment: I am still confused. The third histogram in my post can be generated by summing the pdf-s of D_A and D_B. This is the pdf that generates the waiting times between any successive event, regardless of being X or Y. This pdf is e^(-x \alpha) \alpha + e^(-x \beta) \beta. What is the distribution having this pdf?

Comment: Your conclusion is wrong @IstvánZachar and summing pdfs is meaningless here. I have already explained in my post what is the distribution of the waiting times between the successive events of any type, which is what you are looking for.

Comment: I beg to differ, though I may be wrong. But the way I mix my experimentally generated time differences (two independent Poisson processes with intensities $a$ and $b$, respectively, and then pool all resulting times, sort them, and calculate successive pairwise differences) results in the 3rd histogram, which is NOT the same as generating time differences using a Poisson process with intensity $a$+$b$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Something is wrong with your procedure, since I obtain my result. You may use my code here:

Comment: https://textdoc.co/8sA3hqTmvkPJX6bM

Comment: My guess is that you don't differentiate between *waiting times* and *arrival times*, which are the cumulative sum of the waiting times. @IstvánZachar

Comment: Since I have not used either "arrival" or "waiting" times in my post, it cannot be the issue. I have explicitly stated that I have calculated waiting times. However, I tracked down the discrepancy, which was that my Poisson processes ran for different timespans though yielded identical counts. This clearly explains histogram #3, which is obviously not what I want. Thanks for your code and continued patience.

Comment: @IstvánZachar you're welcome